# Liferay 6.2 Documents migration from filesystem to DB

Tags: database, liferay, liferay-6, data-migration

I am going to move from storing document files in filesystem to Database.
I would like to know the following before proceeding.

1. Migration of existing documents in filesystem, is executed through control panel by selecting the DBStore hook. Is this right? Do I need to perform some other actions?
2. Regarding performance, what are the drawbacks/advantages of such a change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yes. If you want to store in some other database than the default, you'll need to configure that connection
2. it depends (TM). Measure: If your database or network connection to the database are currently the bottleneck, you're adding to this. If something else is the bottleneck limiting your installation, nothing will happen

Comment: About 1. You mean in a database different than the one I'm using currently, right ?